# if font-size is 100%, how can I make the headers bigger?

Tags: css

I have defined my Font-size as 98% in the body, just as follows:

```
body {
   color: #6B6B6B;
   background-color: #262626;

   font-family: arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 98%;
   line-height: 1.32;
   text-align: center;

   -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

The problem now, how can I make my `h1` a bit bigger? and `h2` big as well?

I tried:

```
h1 {
   font-size: 120%;
   line-height: 1;
}
```

But I don't think this is right, do I need to use px or em for my headers?

Comment: Well, this is right. For h1, 100% are the 98% from the body

Comment: Whats the problem with the `120%`? Its valid css.

Comment: In addition to not explaining what you really want and why you think the obvious solution is not right, your title does not match the question text (100% vs. 98%). It’s a small difference, but still; and 98% looks rather odd, so the real problem might be “what does ‘%’ mean in CSS?”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `%` is valid `CSS`.

You can have

```
h1{
    font-size:150%;
}
```

Comment: So I can safely use %100+?

Comment: You can use any `%` you want! `291%` if you really wanted! @Loai

Comment: Thank you very much, I just wanted to make sure I can use + 100 in % and it won't be a invalid CSS or bad for cross browsers and devices!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `em` what is able to scale your font. For example:

```
h1 {
   font-size: 1.2em;
   line-height: 1;
}
```

is equal to 120% of current font size.

Here you have [useful article](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/) about font sizing.

Answer (score -1):

Base on @verbose-mode comment, you can avoid the h1 and h2 elements to be selected by using the `:not` selector:

```
body {
   color: #6B6B6B;
   background-color: #262626;

   font-family: arial, sans-serif;
   line-height: 1.32;
   text-align: center;

   -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

body *:not(h1):not(h2){
    font-size: 30%;
}
```

You can see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3DsX/).